# at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source) while uploading recorded audio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload recorded audio to `FireBase databse` for recording the audio i used service and the file upload successfully on `fireBase` storage but when i get response from `server` then the app get freeze and and got above error in my logs.I try to find solution on `stackoverflow`  but could not find the solution why i get this error..please help..

**My code is:**

```
 void uploadAudio(String audiofilePath) {
        final String name = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss", new Date()).toString();
        StorageReference filePath = storageReference.child(name+"_recording.3gp");
        final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(audiofilePath));
        UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putFile(uri);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+downloadUrl,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                AudioMessageModel model = new AudioMessageModel("audio",downloadUrl.toString(),name,"",uri);

                ChatMessage newMessage = new ChatMessage(null,mCurrentUserId,mRecipientId,
                        null,null,Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()+"",null,model);
                messageChatDatabase.push().setValue(newMessage);

            }
        });
    }
```

**Error:**

> at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)

```
ActivityManager: ANR in com.tecorb.chatapp (com.tecorb.chatapp/.ui.ChatActivity)
                                                  PID: 20318
                                                  Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 38.  Wait queue head age: 5514.5ms.)
                                                  Load: 5.16 / 4.38 / 4.34
                                                  CPU usage from 38050ms to 0ms ago (2017-10-12 22:59:56.300 to 2017-10-12 23:00:34.350):
                                                    32% 1525/system_server: 19% user + 13% kernel / faults: 10293 minor 46 major
                                                    4.4% 690/adbd: 0.7% user + 3.7% kernel / faults: 11288 minor
                                                    1.5% 549/surfaceflinger: 0.6% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 377 minor
                                                    4% 547/servicemanager: 1.8% user + 2.2% kernel
                                                    3.7% 1867/com.android.systemui: 2.9% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 4695 minor 5 major
                                                    3.6% 2951/android.process.acore: 2.3% user + 1.3% kernel / faults: 816 minor
                                                    0.1% 727/mediaserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 221 minor
                                                    2.3% 20112/com.google.android.apps.maps: 1.8% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 7917 minor 31 major
                                                    2.1% 8715/com.jio.join: 1.4% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 3809 minor 9 major
                                                    1.7% 1831/sdcard: 0.2% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 2 minor
                                                    0% 2924/com.miui.home: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1470 minor 2 major
                                                    0% 723/media.codec: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 450 minor 2 major
                                                    1.4% 437/logd: 0.7% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 6 minor
                                                    1.4% 11067/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.9% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 511 minor 18 major
                                                    0.8% 2062/com.android.phone: 0.5% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 202 minor
                                                    0.8% 332/mmc-cmdqd/0: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
                                                    0.8% 17297/com.google.android.gms: 0.6% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 1896 minor 15 major
                                                    0.8% 19941/kworker/u16:0: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
                                                    0.6% 730/gx_fpd: 0% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 95 minor 1 major
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second argument of Toast.makeText()
replace

```
""+downloadUrl
```

with

```
downloadUrl.toString()
```